# How does Spring routing work? Is there a way to access it?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm building a rest API in Spring. Is there a way to tap into the routing to do a lookup?

Is there a table somewhere? 
Given a full route `/someobject/a` with an `ACCEPT` header of "whatever", is there a way I can tell what controller and method it will get routed to, Or do I need to build that map myself?

I asked a similar question in a different way and was suggested to use Spring AOP which I tried with `@Before`, but it doesn't work in some of the cases I need. Specifically, if there are validation annotations on the method parameters and the validation fails, it doesn't make it to the `join` point. Doesn't make it to the `@AfterThrowing` either.

Comment: Not directly, unfortunately. This is my major longstanding objection to the usefulness of the Spring HATEOAS library--you can generate a link from an entity, but you can't figure out what entity a link is supposed to reference.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I have access to the HttpServletRequest and the context… anything hidden in there? Really the end game is to find out if a request will be going to a method that has PreAuthorize on it.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- seems like it has something to do with RequestMappingHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter…

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- BINGO! RequestMappingHandlerMapping is exposed as a bean and if you call the getHandler() method on the servlet request it gives you the info (in the debugger lol)… once I get this ironed out, I'll post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those trying to figure this out in the future, yes it is indeed possible. The routing is exposed as a bean:

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;
```

You need the HttpServletRequest object which you can get from here if you don't have it already:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Then you just call:

```
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod)requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
```

My specific need was to get the PreAuthorize attribute, but you can do anything with the HandlerMethod object:

```
PreAuthorize preauthorize = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
```